# how to label the bar charts in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

i am plotting a graph with bar charts in python using pandas and matplotlib and i need to change the label of my x axis.
here's my code :

```
data['impact'] = data['impact'].abs()
yearly = data.groupby(data.index.month)['impact'].mean()

print yearly
ttl = 'la moyenne mensuelle des impacts du 2006 a 2010'
ax = yearly.plot(kind='bar', title = ttl)
xlab = 'les mois du 2006 a 2010 '
ax.set_xlabel(xlab, fontsize=20, ha='center')
ylab = 'la moyenne des impacts'
ax.set_ylabel(ylab, fontsize=20, ha='center')
```

it gives me this result :
[click here to see my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm33j.png)

so now, my request is how can i change the label of months in the x axix from :

```
[1,2,3,4,...,12] to ['jan','Fev','Mar','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
```

I tried this :

```
 labels = ['jan','Fev','Mar','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
 plt.xticks(labels, rotation='vertical')
```

but i got this error :
ValueError: could not convert string to float: jan

any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```